# Equation of a circle in a new frame.

Tags: geometry

I have the picture under. I want the equation of this circle in the frame $(x',y')$ where $x'=x+a$ and $y'=y+b$. It's obvious that it's $(x'+a)^2+(y'+a)^2=1$, but I don't get it by calculation. This is my method: $$(x',y')=(x+a,y+b) \implies (x,y)=(x'-a,y'-b)$$
and thus since $x^2+y^2=1$, we get $$(x'-a)^2+(y'-b)^2=1.$$
Therefore the equation of the circle in $(x',y')$ is $(x'-a)2+(y'-b)^2=1$ and not $(x'+a)^2+(y'+b)^2=1$.

What's wrong ?

[image: picture]

Comment: Remember that you are not substituting (your first result), but rather changing your coordinate system (your second result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The wrong is the **transformation from the first coordinate system to the second**. The change is as follows : $x=a+x',\,\, y=b+y'$. Draw the radius vector from $O$ to $O'$ and the radius vector in $O'x'y'$ of an arbitrary point $M$. Then you will see the connection between them : $$\vec {OM}=\vec{OO'}+\vec{O'M}$$ where $\vec{O'M}=(x',y')$ are the coordinates of $M$ in the second coordinate system. $\vec{OM}$ are the coordinates of $M$ in the first coordinate system, and $\vec{OO'}$ is the translation vector $(a,b)$.

Comment: Ooohhh... you right :-) Thanks a lot,

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice,

the equation of the circle in $(x, y)$ is $x^2+y^2=1$ with center $(0, 0)$ & radius $1$

Now, shifting (without rotation of coordinate axes) the origin $(0, 0)$ at the point $(a, b)$, the coordinates of old frame $(x, y)$ & $(x', y')$ are related as $$x=x'+a, \ y=y'+b$$

Hence, the equation of the circle in $(x', y')$  becomes $$\color{red}{(x'+a)^2+(y'+a)^2=1}$$ 
the above equation represents the circle with center $(-a, -b)$ & a radius $1$ in new frame $(x', y')$ which is true because the center $(0, 0)$ in old frame now becomes $(0-a, 0-b)=(-a, -b)$ in new frame $(x', y')$ while the radius is unchanged.